# evaluating an indefinite and improper integral

Tags: definite-integrals

$$
I=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{Q_1(a,\sqrt{by})}{1+cy}dy
$$
$a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive coefficients. $Q_1$ is Marcum $q$-function. This integral is part of a problem which I'm trying to solve it and after lot's of effort the problem transform into two parts. For solving the second part(the question I asked you) I can't go through, unfortunately.

Comment: This is not a definite integral but an improper one.

Comment: @Timbuc No, it's a definite integral AND an improper one.

Comment: @DavidH Point taken, though I think it may depend on definition.